# Is there a canonical name of the dot product of the transpose of a symmetric matrix and itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $\displaystyle A = \left[\begin{matrix}-2 & -1\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$

$A^TA = \displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}4 & 2\\2 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$

$A^TA$ is a common used quantity, so, is there a canonical name of $A^TA$?

Comment: It's so brief as it is, there's really no need for a name. Why clutter the already large collection of math terms?

Comment: I see no "dot product", which usually refers to vectors. This is a matrix product. But see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product

Comment: [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) is one possibility.

Comment: It is the quantity which it is equal to the identity if and only if $A$ is orthogonal (this comment is semi-sarcastic).